# How to properly position labels with leader lines on faceted pie charts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I'm trying to recreate a figure but am unable to get the positioning of the labels inside the pie charts right.

This is my current code:

```
ggplot(flying63, aes(x = '', y = percentage, fill = baby_on_plane)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, position = position_fill()) +
  coord_polar('y') +
  facet_grid(gender ~ age) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f%%", percentage)),
             position = position_fill(), size = 3, max.time = 8) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

However, I want the labels to look as follows:
[image]

##### Update:

input data:

```
flying63 <- structure(list(gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), age = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("18-29", "30-44", "45-60", 
"> 60"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), baby_on_plane = c("Yes, very rude", 
"Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", 
"Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", 
"Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", 
"Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", 
"Yes, somewhat rude", "No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude", 
"No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude", 
"No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude"
), n = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 15L, 5L, 23L, 11L, 14L, 10L, 
19L, 34L, 19L, 17L, 47L, 62L, 75L, 71L, 35L, 50L, 74L, 55L), 
    percentage = c(6.66666666666667, 6.41025641025641, 6.31578947368421, 
    6.89655172413793, 12.9032258064516, 11.5789473684211, 13.8888888888889, 
    6.49350649350649, 30.6666666666667, 14.1025641025641, 14.7368421052632, 
    11.4942528735632, 30.6451612903226, 35.7894736842105, 17.5925925925926, 
    22.0779220779221, 62.6666666666667, 79.4871794871795, 78.9473684210526, 
    81.6091954022989, 56.4516129032258, 52.6315789473684, 68.5185185185185, 
    71.4285714285714), label_position = c(3.33333333333333, 3.2051282051282, 
    3.1578947368421, 3.44827586206896, 6.4516129032258, 5.78947368421055, 
    6.94444444444445, 3.24675324675324, 15.3333333333333, 7.05128205128205, 
    7.3684210526316, 5.7471264367816, 15.3225806451613, 17.8947368421052, 
    8.7962962962963, 11.038961038961, 31.3333333333333, 39.7435897435898, 
    39.4736842105263, 40.8045977011494, 28.2258064516129, 26.3157894736842, 
    34.2592592592593, 35.7142857142857)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), age = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("18-29", "30-44", 
    "45-60", "> 60"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), baby_on_plane = c("No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude"), .rows = structure(list(
        17L, 9L, 1L, 18L, 10L, 2L, 19L, 11L, 3L, 20L, 12L, 4L, 
        21L, 13L, 5L, 22L, 14L, 6L, 23L, 15L, 7L, 24L, 16L, 8L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -24L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: Wellcome to stackoverflow. Could you please provide some of your data? For example `dput(flying63)`.

Comment: @TarJae, thank you for your response. I added the dput output

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

I fudged up some data so I could work on this. I think what you are looking for is the `box.padding = ...` argument. You can play with the value to change the length of the offsets.

```
flying63 <- tibble(percentage = rep(c(80,7,13),4),
                   baby_on_plane=rep(c('Not Rude','Somewhat','Very'),4),
                   gender = sample(c('M','F'),12, replace = T),
                   age = sample(c('18','30','45','60'),12,replace = T))


ggplot(flying63, aes(x = '', y = percentage, fill = baby_on_plane)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, position = position_fill()) +
  coord_polar('y') +
  facet_grid(gender ~ age) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f%%", percentage)),
                   position = position_fill(), size = 3, max.time = 8,
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                   box.padding = 1) + # This is the change
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me to posting the answer, but I will keep mine cause I think `vjust` provides some value. Cheers. +1

Comment: @ M-- I just came here to comment to the OP that he should look to your answer as I agree the addition of `vjust` adds some nice clarity to the label origins!

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

datasets::iris %>% 
  transmute(age = as.numeric(cut_number(Sepal.Length,3)),
         gender = as.numeric(cut_number(Petal.Length,2)),
         respond = Species) %>% 
  mutate(n1 = n(), .by = c(age, gender, respond)) %>%
  mutate(n2 = n(), .by = c(age, gender)) %>%
  mutate(percentage = 100 * n1/n2, .by = c(age, gender)) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  arrange(age, gender) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = '', y = percentage, fill = respond)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, position = position_fill()) +
  coord_polar('y') +
  facet_grid(gender ~ age) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = sprintf("%.0f%%", percentage)),
                   position = position_fill(vjust = 0.2), size = 3, max.time = 8, 
                   box.padding = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To place label in the middle of each bar in a stacked barplot, you need to set the vjust parameter of position_stack():

What you need is `position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)`
Here is the original example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

flying63 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = percentage, fill = baby_on_plane)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percentage, 1), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            size = 6)+
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  facet_grid(gender ~ paste("Age: ",age)) +
  labs(fill = "Baby on plane")+
  theme_void()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=16),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

data:

```
flying63 <- structure(list(gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), age = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("18-29", "30-44", "45-60", 
"> 60"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), baby_on_plane = c("Yes, very rude", 
"Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", 
"Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", "Yes, very rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", 
"Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", 
"Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, somewhat rude", 
"Yes, somewhat rude", "No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude", 
"No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude", 
"No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude", "No, not at all rude"
), n = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 15L, 5L, 23L, 11L, 14L, 10L, 
19L, 34L, 19L, 17L, 47L, 62L, 75L, 71L, 35L, 50L, 74L, 55L), 
    percentage = c(6.66666666666667, 6.41025641025641, 6.31578947368421, 
    6.89655172413793, 12.9032258064516, 11.5789473684211, 13.8888888888889, 
    6.49350649350649, 30.6666666666667, 14.1025641025641, 14.7368421052632, 
    11.4942528735632, 30.6451612903226, 35.7894736842105, 17.5925925925926, 
    22.0779220779221, 62.6666666666667, 79.4871794871795, 78.9473684210526, 
    81.6091954022989, 56.4516129032258, 52.6315789473684, 68.5185185185185, 
    71.4285714285714), label_position = c(3.33333333333333, 3.2051282051282, 
    3.1578947368421, 3.44827586206896, 6.4516129032258, 5.78947368421055, 
    6.94444444444445, 3.24675324675324, 15.3333333333333, 7.05128205128205, 
    7.3684210526316, 5.7471264367816, 15.3225806451613, 17.8947368421052, 
    8.7962962962963, 11.038961038961, 31.3333333333333, 39.7435897435898, 
    39.4736842105263, 40.8045977011494, 28.2258064516129, 26.3157894736842, 
    34.2592592592593, 35.7142857142857)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), age = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("18-29", "30-44", 
    "45-60", "> 60"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), baby_on_plane = c("No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude", "No, not at all rude", 
    "Yes, somewhat rude", "Yes, very rude"), .rows = structure(list(
        17L, 9L, 1L, 18L, 10L, 2L, 19L, 11L, 3L, 20L, 12L, 4L, 
        21L, 13L, 5L, 22L, 14L, 6L, 23L, 15L, 7L, 24L, 16L, 8L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -24L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```